# LEFT JOIN doesn't behave as expected as gives NULLs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am completing [this challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem) from HackerRank.

It asks:

*Pivot the Occupation column in OCCUPATIONS so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation. The output column headers should be Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor, respectively.*

It involves this table of data:

```
Name       Occupation     
Ashley      Professor 
Samantha Actor 
Julia         Doctor 
Britney     Professor 
Maria        Professor 
Meera       Professor 
Priya         Doctor 
Priyanka    Professor 
Jennifer     Actor 
Ketty         Actor 
Belvet Professor 
Naomi Professor 
Jane Singer 
Jenny Singer 
Kristeen Singer 
Christeen Singer 
Eve Actor 
Aamina Doctor
```

We want to pivot this table by `Occupation` such that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation. The output column headers (which don't actually) should be Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor, respectively.

However, when I run this MySQL code:

```
SELECT d.name, p.name, s.name, a.name 
FROM (
    SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, Name
    FROM OCCUPATIONS, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
    WHERE Occupation = 'Professor'
    ORDER BY Name
    ) p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, Name
    FROM OCCUPATIONS, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
    WHERE Occupation = 'Doctor'
    ORDER BY Name
    ) d ON d.row_number =p.row_number
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, Name
    FROM OCCUPATIONS, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
    WHERE Occupation = 'Singer'
    ORDER BY Name
    ) s ON p.row_number =s.row_number
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, Name
    FROM OCCUPATIONS, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
    WHERE Occupation = 'Actor'
    ORDER BY Name
    ) a ON p.row_number =a.row_number
```

The `LEFT JOIN`s don't behave as expected and I get:

```
NULL Ashley NULL NULL 
NULL Belvet NULL NULL 
NULL Britney NULL NULL 
NULL Maria NULL NULL 
NULL Meera NULL NULL 
NULL Naomi NULL NULL 
NULL Priyanka NULL NULL
```

This doesn't make sense to me -- why does the join produce so many nulls? Does MySQL behave in a way such that you can't number multiple tables? Not clear to me.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your session variables.  Is it also a requirement to number entries in each column?

Comment: You have to be very careful when using the same variable several times throughout the same query (essentially, you can't, so initialise a new variable each time). Anyway, as for a solution to the problem, here's a hint: max(case when ... 'doctor' then... end) doctor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supposing that the reason it isn't matching up the way you think it should is that `@row_number` isn't resetting to 1 for each subquery.

I tested it out, just joining the first two (Professors and Doctors), but using a CROSS JOIN, so I could see all the row_number values.

```
+------------+--------+------------+----------+
| row_number | name   | row_number | name     |
+------------+--------+------------+----------+
|          8 | Aamina |          1 | Ashley   |
|          8 | Aamina |          2 | Belvet   |
|          8 | Aamina |          3 | Britney  |
|          8 | Aamina |          4 | Maria    |
|          8 | Aamina |          5 | Meera    |
|          8 | Aamina |          6 | Naomi    |
|          8 | Aamina |          7 | Priyanka |
|          9 | Julia  |          1 | Ashley   |
|          9 | Julia  |          2 | Belvet   |
|          9 | Julia  |          3 | Britney  |
|          9 | Julia  |          4 | Maria    |
|          9 | Julia  |          5 | Meera    |
|          9 | Julia  |          6 | Naomi    |
|          9 | Julia  |          7 | Priyanka |
|         10 | Priya  |          1 | Ashley   |
|         10 | Priya  |          2 | Belvet   |
|         10 | Priya  |          3 | Britney  |
|         10 | Priya  |          4 | Maria    |
|         10 | Priya  |          5 | Meera    |
|         10 | Priya  |          6 | Naomi    |
|         10 | Priya  |          7 | Priyanka |
+------------+--------+------------+----------+
```

You can see that apparently the row numbers are incremented progressively, and the initial value of 1 in both subqueries has already been done by the time the rows are numbered.

You might be able to fix this by using a distinct user variable in each subquery.

But this query will not work the way you want anyway, for example if you ever have fewer Professors than members of other professions.

Honestly, I would not do this kind of columnar formatting in SQL. Just do four independent queries, fetch all the results into your application, and format into columns as you output. It will be much simpler that way, and simple code is easier to write, easier to debug, easier to maintain.

---

Re your comment:

Fair enough, doing this as a coding challenge is fine, so long as you (and other readers) know that in a real project, doing excessively clever SQL isn't always the best idea.

Since you're doing a coding challenge, you should solve it yourself, so I can't give you the solution that produces the output below. But this is evidence that it's possible (I promise I did not mock up the output, I really copy & pasted it from my terminal window). Good luck!

```
+------------+-----------+--------+-----------+----------+
| row_number | Professor | Doctor | Singer    | Actor    |
+------------+-----------+--------+-----------+----------+
|          1 | Ashley    | Aamina | Christeen | Eve      |
|          2 | Belvet    | Julia  | Jane      | Jennifer |
|          3 | Britney   | Priya  | Jenny     | Ketty    |
|          4 | Maria     | NULL   | Kristeen  | Samantha |
|          5 | Meera     | NULL   | NULL      | NULL     |
|          6 | Naomi     | NULL   | NULL      | NULL     |
|          7 | Priyanka  | NULL   | NULL      | NULL     |
+------------+-----------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi, Bill - to be clear, the only reason I was writing this query was for a coding challenge -- see hyperlink in question.

Comment: Yup, I solved it -- thanks for the tip about the variables! I usually use postgres so this was a bit out of my comfort zone.